# Running Script to import database schema in to PostgreSQL via Bash

Tags: sql, database, bash, postgresql, scripting

I need to write a script that imports a DB schema in to PostgreSQL database which will run as part of a larger build script. I run the following script as root.

```
#Change ownership of copied Schema
chown postgres:postgres /var/lib/pgsql/ddl.sql

su - postgres

cd ~

psql -Ubuild test < /var/lib/pgsql/ddl.sql

exit
```

The problem I have is, to actually allow the import to work I have to type exit after the script has finished executing. I have tried adding an additional exit at the end of the script but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Any ideas would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to place it on the background with &:

```
#!/bin/bash
chown postgres:postgres /var/lib/pgsql/ddl.sql
su - postgres
cd ~
psql -Ubuild test < /var/lib/pgsql/ddl.sql &
```

Make sure you run it in a script probably to prevent job control.

If it pauses during process try to adding more configurations:

```
set +o monitor
psql -Ubuild test < /var/lib/pgsql/ddl.sql &
disown
```

And are you sure you still need to `su` to `postgres` when you already specify a different user with `-Ubuild`?

Comment: I stopped it running as root and that fixed the problem right up for me. Thanks.

Comment: *I stopped it running as the postgres user.